# Probability of average people coming to work

Tags: probability, statistics

I am working on this:

> A restaurant employs $9$ people. $2$ bartenders, $3$ waiters and $4$ work in the kitchen. It has been observed that
>   on any day the probability of an employee to call in sick is $2\%$ for the bartenders, $3\%$ for the waiters and $1\%$ for
>   the kitchen staff.
>
> Calculate the average number of the employees coming to work.

I did this:

> P(no employee missing) = $0.98$^$2$ * $0.97$^$3$ * $0.99$^$4$ = $0.842$
>
> avg number of people coming to work = $9$ *P(no employee is missing) = $9*0.842$ = $7.578$ = $8$

But I have a feeling it might not be correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: First, you should consider each group of people separately. Then the number of people in each group going to work follow a binomial distribution. The average or mean in a binomial distribution is $np$.

Comment: so I find the average of each group i.e. for the kitchen staff  np = 4 * 0.99 and then add the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of bartenders coming to work is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2}n\cdot\binom{2}{n}\cdot(1-0.02)^n\cdot(0.02)^{2-n}=1.96$$

---

The expected number of waiters coming to work is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{3}n\cdot\binom{3}{n}\cdot(1-0.03)^n\cdot(0.03)^{3-n}=2.91$$

---

The expected number of cooks coming to work is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{4}n\cdot\binom{4}{n}\cdot(1-0.01)^n\cdot(0.01)^{4-n}=3.96$$

---

Hence the expected number of people coming to work is $1.96+2.91+3.96=8.83$.